# React Native - ¿Cómo debería realizar un push() valiéndome de argumentos enviados a una función?

Tags: array, funciones, react-native

Quisiera saber el modo de realizar un **push()** valiéndome de argumentos enviados a una función.

Por ejemplo, si realizo un push() de la siguiente manera: *objetoUsuario.campoNombre.push("Pedro");*

**¿Cómo podría realizarlo utilizando parámetros enviados a una función?**

Siguiendo un esquema del tipo *parametroObjeto.parametroCampo.push(parametroNombre);*

A modo de ejemplo, sería un código similar al siguiente:

```
// La función sería algo así
const funcionAgregarRegistro = (objeto, campo, valor) => {
    try {
        objeto.campo.push(valor); // <=== ésto es lo que debo resolver !!
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error.");
        return;
    }
    return console.log("Datos incorporados.")
};

// Luego llamaría a la función desde un botón. Por ejemplo:
<Button title="Agregar usuario" onPress={() => funcionAgregarRegistro("objetoUsuario", "campoNombre", "Pedro")}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haberte entendido, si lo que quieres es acceder la propiedad de un objeto por medio del nombre de la misma, entonces puedes hacerlo por medio de paréntesis cuadrados `[]`:

```js
const frutas = {
  rojas: ["manzana", "cereza"],
  amarillas: ["banano", "piña"]
}

const funcionAgregarRegistro = (objeto, campo, valor) => {
  try {
    objeto[campo].push(valor);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error.");
    return;
  }
  console.log("Datos incorporados.");
  console.log(objeto);
};

funcionAgregarRegistro(frutas, "rojas", "tomate");
funcionAgregarRegistro(frutas, "amarillas", "maracuya");
```

Este tipo de asignación se llama *Notación por Corchetes*, te dejo [esta documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#notaci.c3.b3n_por_corchetes) que incluye todos los métodos para acceder las propiedades de un objeto.

Comment: Era eso lo que buscaba!. Perfecto. Leeré la documentación que me indicás. Muy agradecido @FranAcuna